# Unable to pre process a .skt file as before

Tags: xetex, indic

When using the command `> skt file.skt`, I get the following error message:
'skt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{skt}
\begin{document}
{\skt o. nama.h "sivAya}
\end{document}
```

I use MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: BTW have you considered using xelatex/lualatex, with Unicode input and a Unicode font for output? This is both a more standard way to input, and gives you a choice of any modern Opentype font (though [I'm aware](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296266/old-sanskrit-fonts-and-unicode-input/358887#358887) the old font with `skt` package has some reasons for being preferred).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the file skt.c is missing from the new update. This can be downloaded from CTAN and then needs to be compiled. Once that is done, things work as before.