# Devnag, Skt, Itrans packages missing in Texlive Ubuntu 1604

Tags: packages, languages, indic

I installed TeXlive-full in Ubuntu 1604 using the command
sudo apt-get install texlive-full.
I find the following packages missing:

skt (Sanskrit for LaTeX2e by Charles Wikner)

devnag (Devanagari TeX 2.17 )

Itrans

All these packages were available in earlier versions like Ubuntu 1204
and could be installe3d using the usual "sudo apt-get install" command.
The Ubuntu software Centre also cannot find these packages.
Are there Debian packages available for these packages, which one can install by downloading them?. (There must be, since they were all present in earlier Ubuntu versions).

Also,where is the LOCAL TEXMF tree located in Ubuntu Texlive, where
I can manually place missing packages and style files?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408326/using-devanagri-package-in-latex and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367300/unable-to-pre-process-a-skt-file-as-before for some related stuff (`skt.c` seems to be no longer distributed with TeX Live and needs to be downloaded from CTAN).

Comment: @Narayanaswami I wish to install these packages. Could you please comment, from where you obtain the skt pre-processor and how to compile it? Thank you

Comment: @Srinath Just download [`skt.c` from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/sanskrit/skt.c) and compile it like any other C file: it has no dependencies. I don't know why this stopped being distributed in TeX Live though… BTW have you seen the earlier answers and are you sure you can't use `xelatex` / `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 1):

No packages named "skt" or "devnag" on CTAN. There are however packages "sanskrit" and "velthuis" (for devangari); both included under those names in TeX-live. Perhaps those are the ones you need?

Comment: Thanks.  All the fonts and font definitions needed for processing .tex files in Devnag and Skt are there, but only the pre-processor for converting .skt to .tex  is missing.  I can obtain skt.c and compile it.